# Erro na edição de um registo utilizando Spring MVC e thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Boas colegas, estou a estudar Spring atráves de umas video aulas e agora estou com o seguinte problema que não consigo solucionar já fiz de tudo que estava no meu alcance. O problema é o seguinte quando quero clicar no link que supostamente iria-me direcionar a uma pagina que permitira a alteração de um registo emite o seguinte erro no navegador de referir que quando ponho o camino na url a pagina abre, mais quando chamo é que o erro é disparado. O que devo fazer?:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 02 17:14:13 CAT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [tarefas/alterar/1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

abaixo está o elemento da view que chama a pagina de edicao:

```
        <div class="card-footer bg-light">
            <p>
                <a th:href="@{/tarefas/alterar/{id}(id=${tarefa.id})}">Alterar</a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

abaixo está action do controller para a alteracao:

```
@GetMapping("/alterar/{id}")
    public ModelAndView alterar(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        Tarefa tarefa = rt.getOne(id);
        mv.addObject("tarefa", tarefa);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping("/alterar")
    public ModelAndView alterar(@Valid Tarefa tarefa, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        if (tarefa.getDataExpiracao() == null) {
            result.rejectValue("dataExpiracao", "tarefa.dataExpiracaoInvalida", "A data de expiração obrigatória.");
        } else {
            if (tarefa.getDataExpiracao().before(new Date())) {
                result.rejectValue("dataExpiracao", "tarefa.dataExpiracaoInvalida",
                        "A data de expiração não pode ser anterior à data actual.");
            }
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            mv.setViewName("tarefas/alterar");
            mv.addObject(tarefa);
        } else {
            mv.setViewName("redirect:/tarefas/listar");
            rt.save(tarefa);
        }
        return mv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver o meu problema, não tinha posto o trecho de codigo que redirecionava para a pagina na qual iria editar. Abaixo deixo o codigo da action modificada

```
@GetMapping("/alterar/{id}")
    public ModelAndView alterar(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        Tarefa tarefa = rt.getOne(id);
        mv.addObject("tarefa", tarefa);
        mv.setViewName("/tarefas/alterar")
        return mv;
    }
```